# Web site not rendering properly with IE10 +

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I have few web site running on aspx using older version of DNN 4.x. All site are rendering properly on Google Chrome, Fire Fox, Opera etc... but starting with IE 10x +, the navigation pane started to render improperly...

The site in question is the following :

http://www.westendsports.ca

I suspect a CSS failure, but I haven't been able to pin point the issue. I really need to fix this issue for the client, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Is it anything more than the nav menu you're unhappy with? In that case, could you post a jsFiddle with only the relevant code?

Comment: Your site is broken in every rendering mode I tried on IE11. You already have an `X-UA-Compatible` tag forcing it to IE9 mode, so essentially - it's just too old and broken to still be saved. Start over before it starts to fail in all browsers.

Comment: Site makes some assumptions based on user-agent. In IE11 in emulation mode (Edge) when Chrome user-agent string is passed - it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to the latest DNN. Yours is 6 year old.

Comment: Yep, I know upgrading is the solution, but it's hard to sell to the client... No luck with <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1" /> The black bar does format properly, but the menu items are not displayed.

Comment: I think you better try to sell the upgrade. Software circa 2008 has no idea what IE10/11 are and besides visible ones there could be others issues turning out to be more expensive or impossible to fix at the end